# Solving integral of spherical means

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

The solution of 3D wave equation is given by Kirchhoff's formula as
$$u(t,\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi c^2t^2}\int_{\partial S(\mathbf{r},ct)} \bigg[u_0(\mathbf{r'}) + (\mathbf{r'}-\mathbf{r})\cdot \nabla u_0(\mathbf{r'})\bigg]d\sigma(\mathbf{r'}) + 
\frac{1}{4\pi c^2t}\int_{\partial S(\mathbf{r},ct)} u_1(\mathbf{r'}) d\sigma(\mathbf{r'})$$
where $u_0(\mathbf{r}) = u(t=0,\mathbf{r})$, $u_1(\mathbf{r}) = u_t(t=0,\mathbf{r})$ and $\partial S(\mathbf{r},ct)$ is surface of sphere at $\mathbf{r}$ of radius $ct$.

I want to calculate  $u(t,\mathbf{r})$ when $u_0(\mathbf{r})=0$ and $u_1(\mathbf{r})=r^2$.

In this case the first integral will be zero. So, the solution should be
$$u(t,\mathbf{r}) =  
\frac{1}{4\pi c^2t}\int_{\partial S(\mathbf{r},ct)} \mathbf{r'}^2 d\sigma(\mathbf{r'})$$
**How can I solve this integral?** My attempt was to put $d\sigma(r)=r^2\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$, this way the answer is $r^4/c^2t$ which is wrong. [Here (on page 1, example 1),](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/teaching/m435s14/WaveEquationExamples.pdf) it says that the correct solution is $r^2 t + t^3$ (here they have used $c=1$).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve this integral?

You have the right idea but I think you missed the bounds of the integral.  If you look at the typical solution to the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation), you will note that the limits of the integral are something like $r \pm c \ t$ and the cross section is something like $d\sigma = r \ dr \ \sin{\theta} \ d\theta d\phi$.  If you integrate $r^{3} dr$ with the limits $r \pm c \ t$, you find something like:
$$
\int_{r - c \ t}^{r + c \ t} \ dr \ r^{3} = 2 \ c \ r \left( r^{2} \ t + c^{2} t^{3} \right) \tag{0}
$$
which is remarkably close to the result you suggest is correct (within a factor of $2 \ c \ r$).  The rest is arithmetic.